# Going from Friends Profile to Friends Data Firebase

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

My application uses Firebase with Facebook login. 
I have managed to set up my app so that the user has their profile and can view other users profiles.
When the current user goes on to their friends profile they see their data.

I have a bar button item on their friends profile that links to a tableView displaying more data but I can only get this tableview to display the current users data and not their friends.
Let me show what I have so far.

The current user can view their friends images in a collection view and select an image to take them to that specific profile.

```
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("FriendsProfile", sender: self.usersArray[indexPath.row])
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    super.prepareForSegue(segue, sender: sender)


    let navVc = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
    let friendsVc = navVc.viewControllers.first as! FriendsViewController
    friendsVc.receiverData = sender

}
```

Then once they are on the friends profile in order to display the friends image, name and so on in the view did load I call:

```
    let imageUrl = NSURL(string: receiverData?.objectForKey("profile_pic") as! String)

    let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageUrl!)

    friendsImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
   self.configureName(receiverData?.objectForKey("Name")as? String)
```

On this page, is a bar button item that will take the user to a table view displaying more data but I can only currently display the users data and not their specific friends based on who's profile they selected.

The database I'm accessing looks as follows:

```
user-posts
       user-id
             key
               title:
               notes:
```

And I access it by setting up the code as follows in `FriendsTopicList.m`:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


self.ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];

self.dataSource = [[FriendsDataSource alloc] initWithQuery:[self getQuery] modelClass:[Topic class]  
cellReuseIdentifier:@"post" view:self.tableView];




[self.dataSource populateCellWithBlock:^(FriendsTableViewCell *_Nonnull cell, Topic *_Nonnull topics) {




    cell.textLabel.text = topics.title;


    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(16/255.0) green:(17/255.0) blue:(23/255.0) alpha:1];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:18];

    UIView *selectionColour = [[UIView alloc] init];
    selectionColour.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColour;
}];

self.tableView.dataSource = self.dataSource;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
//    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];




}


-(NSString *)getUid {
    return [FIRAuth auth].currentUser.uid;

}
```

And then referencing that code in the view that contains the tableView called `MyFriendsTopics.h:` with a firebaseQuery

```
@interface MyFriendsTopics : FriendsTopicsList
```

Here is the query:

```
-(FIRDatabaseQuery *)getQuery {


return [[self.ref child:@"user-posts"] child:[super getUid]]; 
}
```

Now I know the getUid is the reason the current users data is displayed, but I'm at a loss as to what should be in its place to display the friends details. I'm just very confused and need pointing in the right direction.

Do I need to pass a dictionary as the sender with the bar button Item on the Friends Profile? And call that in the view did load as the reference for `cell.textLabel`?

Comment: Any help would be appreciated, i'm pretty much losing my mind at the moment